# "No such file or directory", but the file exists

Tags: python, files, executable

I copied some files to Ubuntu (running on VirtualBox). Trying to open the said copied files and get an error. I'm not entirely sure how the file directory system works, but I used `cp` command to copy one of the files.  Is (and other files that were just copied into the folder manually) shows up in the right folder with ls command.  But when I try to execute the file, I get the following error:

```
qiime@qiime-VirtualBox:~$ usr/bin/varscore_pipeline -bo Desktop/Shared_Folder/VARSCORE/C_albicans.fasta Desktop/Shared_Folder/VARSCORE/tmp/poo.csv
bash: usr/bin/varscore_pipeline: usr/bin/python2.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I run the `ls /usr/bin/` command I can see the file `varscore_pipeline` in there, so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`varscore_pipeline` is a Python script. It begins with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line that points to the interpreter that must execute the script. The path to the interpreter is `usr/bin/python2.6`, and this file doesn't exist.

First, that line is wrong. The shebang line must have an absolute path. Change `#!usr/bin/python2.6` to `#!/usr/bin/python2.6`.

Depending on your version of Ubuntu, you may or may not have `/usr/bin/python2.6`. If you only have a later version such as 2.7, change the shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/python2`. It is highly unlikely that the program would work with 2.6 but not 2.7. Python 2.x versions are upward compatible. (But don't change to `/usr/bin/python3`, there are incompatibilities between Python 2 and Python 3.)

See [/bin/sh: ./check-dependencies.pl: not found — but check-dependencies.pl exists!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53097/bin-sh-check-dependencies-pl-not-found-but-check-dependencies-pl-exists/53163#53163) for more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file in question does not have CRLF chars (visible as ^M in `vi`), that is, DOS-style line end char sequences. Sometimes they are not visible in various terminals/editors, while bash tries to run a script with interpreter like `/bin/bash^M`, which doesn't exist, hence the error.